# Calculating average multiple numbers in a map of objects

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, average, java-8

I have a map of the format

```
Map<String, List<TableDTO>>

public class TableDTO {
    private String countryName;
    private String sourceName;
    private int year;
    private Double usageValue;
    private Double powerUsers;

    //Setter & Getters

}
```

I want to find the average of usageValues and powerUsers and still maintain the TableDTO structure and the usageValue can be null, if it null ignore that object completely.

```
<Chrome, <UK, Lorem, 2013, 2.90, 5.4>>
<Chrome, <US, Lorem, 2013, 4.10, 1.5>>
<Chrome, <EU, Lorem, 2013, 1.20, 0.22>>
<Chrome, <Asia, Lorem, 2013, 3.90, -1.10>>

<IE, <UK, Lorem, 2013, 1.40, 24.4>>
<IE, <US, Lorem, 2013, 0.90, 14.4>>
<IE, <EU, Lorem, 2013, 2.10, 0>>
<IE, <Asia, Lorem, 2013, 0.90, 0.4>>

<FF, <UK, Lorem, 2013, 0.10, 2.14>>
<FF, <US, Lorem, 2013, 1.10, 4.0>>
<FF, <EU, Lorem, 2013, , 4.4>>
<FF, <Asia, Lorem, 2013, 2.90, 4.4>>
```

Result expected

```
<1, <UK, Lorem, 2013, 1.47, 10.65>>
<2, <US, Lorem, 2013, 2.03, 6.63>>
<3, <Asia, Lorem, 2013, 2.57, 1.23>>
```

For now in the results I have replaced the keys with index, which is fine for now. You will notice that since FF for EU has a null value the entire EU has been ignored, but for the rest I have the average calculated.

How can this be done using Lambda expressions in Java 8, or do I have to iterate through?

**Update 1:**
This is as far as I got for now:

```
1. 
Map<String, List<TableDTO>> dump = mapOfAllData.values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TableDTO::getCountryName));

Which give me a map with country names and the DTO orderd

2. 
  dump.values().stream().flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                .filter((o -> !o.getUsageValue().isEmpty()))
                .collect(Collectors.mapping(TableDTO::getUsageValue, Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::parseDouble)));
```

Basically gets the average, but does not remove the DTO in which the usageValue is empty, which I am trying at the moment to resolve.

**Update 2:**

I managed to remove the unwanted countries from my map.

I am trying to figure out how to find the average of two elements, I have this expression

```
 newMap.values().stream().flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.mapping(TableDTO::usageValue, Collectors.averagingDouble(s -> s.isEmpty() ? Double.NaN : Double.parseDouble(s))));
                       // Collectors.mapping(TableDTO::powerUsers, Collectors.averagingDouble(c -> c.isEmpty() ? Double.NaN : Double.parseDouble(c))));
```

but am unable to get the average for powerUsers.

Comment: This is similar to your previous question - it would be easier if you showed the code you have and what doesn't work.

Comment: @assylias, to be honest, I am still not getting around it, my problem is that I do not have any mentor to help me learn Java itself, so I am relying more on forums and Javadocs

Comment: @victor: Especially if you want to learn, you should attempt to solve the problem on your own first. Asking almost the same question here indicates not much learning success and suggests that you should question your learning method.

Comment: Thanks guys, for you support, I get what you are saying, give me some time and shall post an update.

Comment: What is `getNewIndex()`?

Comment: @Joffery, sorry, fixed it.

Comment: @victor You said your problem was (used to be, at least) filtering out the countries with empty usage values, but you show a call to an `isEmpty()` method that you don't post (and does not exist on `Double` AFAIK. Also, is `IndicatorTableDTO` a former name of `TableDTO`?

Comment: @Joffery, apologies for the type on the Table name; isEmpty() if from the string class, which returns a boolean if the object is empty or not. The average using Double.parseDouble() is only calculated only after I remove all the empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand, you want an average over each `List<TableDTO>` with a `groupBy` `countryName`, `sourceName`, `year` but average are on distinct field ?

I will expect `usagePower` and `powerUsers` to be `Double`, and not String like your code and your use of `Double.parseDouble` suggests.

This code should do it:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class TableDTO {
  private final String countryName;
  private final String sourceName;
  private final int year;
  @Nullable
  private final Double usageValue;
  private final Double powerUsers;

  public TableDTO(final String countryName, final String sourceName, final int year, final Double usageValue,
      final Double powerUsers) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
    this.sourceName = sourceName;
    this.year = year;
    this.usageValue = usageValue;
    this.powerUsers = powerUsers;
  }

  public String getCountryName() {return countryName;}
  public String getSourceName() {return sourceName;}
  public int getYear() {return year;}
  @Nullable public Double getUsageValue() {return usageValue;}
  public Double getPowerUsers() {return powerUsers;}

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TableDTO [countryName=" + countryName + ", sourceName=" + sourceName + ", year=" + year + ", usageValue="
        + usageValue + ", powerUsers=" + powerUsers + "]";
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final java.util.Map<String, java.util.List<TableDTO>> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    final List<TableDTO> chrome = new ArrayList<>();
    chrome.add(new TableDTO("UK", "Lorem", 2013, 2.90, 5.4));
    chrome.add(new TableDTO("US", "Lorem", 2013, 4.10, 1.5));
    chrome.add(new TableDTO("EU", "Lorem", 2013, 1.20, 0.22));
    chrome.add(new TableDTO("Asia", "Lorem", 2013, 3.90, -1.10));
    data.put("Chrome", chrome);

    final List<TableDTO> ie = new ArrayList<>();
    ie.add(new TableDTO("UK", "Lorem", 2013, 1.40, 24.4));
    ie.add(new TableDTO("US", "Lorem", 2013, 0.90, 14.4));
    ie.add(new TableDTO("EU", "Lorem", 2013, 2.10, 0.));
    ie.add(new TableDTO("Asia", "Lorem", 2013, 0.90, 0.4));
    data.put("IE", ie);

    final List<TableDTO> fx = new ArrayList<>();
    fx.add(new TableDTO("UK", "Lorem", 2013, 0.10, 2.14));
    fx.add(new TableDTO("US", "Lorem", 2013, 1.10, 4.0));
    fx.add(new TableDTO("EU", "Lorem", 2013, null, 4.4));
    fx.add(new TableDTO("Asia", "Lorem", 2013, 2.90, 4.4));
    data.put("FX", fx);

    data.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dto -> Arrays.asList(dto.getCountryName(), dto.getSourceName(), dto.getYear())))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .filter(list -> list.stream().map(TableDTO::getUsageValue).noneMatch(Objects::isNull))
        .map(
            values -> {
              final TableDTO root = values.iterator().next();

              final double usageValueAvg = values.stream().map(TableDTO::getUsageValue).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                  .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
              final double powerUsersAvg = values.stream().map(TableDTO::getPowerUsers)
                  .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue));

              return new TableDTO(root.getCountryName(), root.getSourceName(), root.getYear(), usageValueAvg,
                  powerUsersAvg);

            }).forEach(System.out::println);
    ;

  }
}
```

The result is:

```
TableDTO [countryName=UK, sourceName=Lorem, year=2013, usageValue=1.4666666666666666, powerUsers=10.646666666666667]
TableDTO [countryName=US, sourceName=Lorem, year=2013, usageValue=2.033333333333333, powerUsers=6.633333333333333]
TableDTO [countryName=Asia, sourceName=Lorem, year=2013, usageValue=2.5666666666666664, powerUsers=1.2333333333333334]
```

And the explanation: I've taken some of your code to do it.

- Do a `flatMap` over the values of `data`:

  ```
  data.values()
      .stream()
      .flatMap(List::stream)
  ```
- Group your `TableDTO` by some keys: we don't care about the key, the only important thing is that it correctly implements `hashCode` and `equals`. `Arrays.asList` does the job. Otherwise, create a class Tuple which take an array and use `Arrays.hashCode`/`equals`.

  ```
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dto -> Arrays.asList(dto.getCountryName(), dto.getSourceName(), dto.getYear())))
      .values()
      .stream()
  ```

  Since we don't want the list, we select the values and use a stream.
- We filter `TableDTO` which contains an empty `usageValue`:

  ```
      .filter(list -> list.stream().map(TableDTO::getUsageValue).noneMatch(Objects::isNull))
  ```
- Then we do a map, and that where you were failing at finding a solution: because of the group, all `TableDTO` share the same `countryName`, `sourceName` and `year` value. But not the `usageValue` and `powerUsers`.

  Because the list can't be empty, we get the first element.

  ```
      .map(
          values -> {
            final TableDTO root = values.iterator().next();
  ```
- On the other result, we compute the two averages filtering any null values for `usageValue`.

  ```
            final double usageValueAvg = values.stream().map(TableDTO::getUsageValue).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
            final double powerUsersAvg = values.stream().map(TableDTO::getPowerUsers)
                .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
  ```
- Then we return a new `TableDTO` based on the three grouping key, and the two averages.

  ```
            return new TableDTO(root.getCountryName(), root.getSourceName(), root.getYear(), usageValueAvg,
                powerUsersAvg);

          })
  ```
- And we print it, and voilà! :)

  ```
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  ```

I hope it resolve your question.

I tested it in Eclipse, it compile, but it may fails with javac since the compiler does not the same work with Lambdas.

Comment: that you for the explanation I know now where I went wrong. What is the data structure of the final result. I tried to specific Map<String, List>, but I get an error and have to define it as Stream, is this correct? I get to following error - "This is the error Error:(87, 21) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that java.util.stream.Stream<R> conforms to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<TableDTO>>"

Comment: The final result would be a `Stream<TableDTO>`. You'll need to use `collect(Collectors.toList())` to get a `List<TableDTO>`. And if you need to keep information (like "Chrome", etc), then my example is wrong: you'll need an intermediate `map` operation to transform each `Map.Entry<String,List<TableDTO>>` into a `List<BrowserTableDTO>` (assuming the `String` is a browser name ;)).

Comment: thanks, but here is what I did forEach(element -> _finalRank.add((TableDTO) element)); where _finalRank is a List<TableDTO>

Comment: With `List<TableDTO> rank = new ArrayList<>();`, and `forEach(rank::add)`, there are no problem. Unless you updated the code I gave you.